# How to avoid deformations in Make Human imports?

Tags: modeling, makehuman

I am importing and posing characters (started with Blender 2.76b a week ago) from Make Human (V1.0.2). However frequently I get some awful deformations mainly at the shoulder and wrist - see screen shot. It is almost impossible to pose them with their hands behind the head.

Any ideas or hints? Please!

[image]

Comment: About the wrist: better weigh painting or corrective shape-key is the way there.

Comment: I do not think that this question is a duplicate of the link because as described I import the rig from make human. So breaking the rig apart in order to add the elements described would be rather complicated (at least I think so, but I am a Newbie).

Comment: You do not have to rebuild that rig, it should be ok. You just have to animate it properly and not rotate things in positions they are not supposed to be. Use the shoulder to raise the arm.